# Converting elements of a list to a string and then iteratively listing each element in a text file

Tags: python, arrays, string, list

**Consider this simple example**

Suppose that we have the following list:

```
[[2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10]]
```

I would like to write each list in this list as a separate line in a text file. i.e...

```
2 3 4
5 6 7
8 9 10
```

To do that, I seems that you must convert each element to a string because `object.write()` expects a string (is there a better way to do this?). Now, for a single list like [2, 3, 4], I have been doing the following:

```
l = [2, 3, 4]
s = ' '.join(str(x) for x in l)
with open("file_open.txt", "+a") as file_object:
   file_object.write("\n")
   file_object.write(str(s))
```

How do I do this for a more complicated list like `[[2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10]]` where each element is iteratively listed in a text file as

```
2 3 4
5 6 7
8 9 10
```

Note: in the actual case that I am dealing with, it was originally a numpy array that I converted to a list, and it has the form

```
[[[1.5, 7.912834397348988, 148.46579073169295]], [[2.0, 7.912834397348988, 148.46579073169295]],...]]]
```

Like in the simple example that I gave, I need a text file in the form

```
1.5, 7.912834397348988, 148.46579073169295
2.0, 7.912834397348988, 148.46579073169295
```

It does not have to be a list. Would be be easier to keep it as a numpy array?

Comment: simply start joining from the the inside

Comment: Do what you do for a 1-D list for each 1-D list in the 2-D list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`numpy.savetxt`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) to do this

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([[2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10]])
np.savetxt('file_open.txt', data)
```

The default `delimiter` is `' '` and `newline` is `'\n'` but you can pass those arguments if you prefer something else.

If you were to write this by hand, it would look something like

```
data = [[2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10]]
with open('file_open.txt') as f_out:
    for line in data:
        f_out.write(' '.join(str(i) for i in line) + '\n')
```